# SQL Union on Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have a situation with my database model. I have many tables that have similar fields but different information. I need to generate statistics out of it. What is the best way to make combined query on them.

```
TableA
ID name timestamp (created on)

TableB
ID name timestamp (created on)

tableC
ID name timestamp (created on)
........... & So On. Probably 10-15 more similar tables.
```

Query I am looking for is Union, since they all are different data.
What is the best way, I can gather data like Top 100 recent entries etc. I know the naive approach of visiting every table and combining results and then generate stats. Is there any other way.?

```
select * from tableA
union
select * from tableB
union ...... & So on for 10-15 more tables.
```

Desired result is getting the latest entries or searching for results for a particular column (eg - list of all entries with a common name in all tables.)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Edited it and explained a bit more.

Comment: You mention 15 tables with similar column names. Are they separate `entities`?  How do the column names relate to the attributes of those entities? Would it help us to understand the data structures that you are using, if you explained some of the table names and examples of the attributes, given that you have 15 separate tables with the same column names?

Comment: I know it is not best DB Design. All I am looking for is getting a better way to get stats other than iterating through all the records in all tables and showing a combined result.

Comment: I suspect you are missing the point. I need specific example data to understand what problem you are trying to solve. I do not care about your database structure - i just have to understand it. You know what the 15 tables represent and what the column names are. I don't know what they represent and I need to. This is a limitation of me.

Comment: If you don't want to write out the tables all the time, then create a view to `union all` them all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION and select only columns that you need. If there are columns in table A that does not exist in table B, use null on that place...

```
select colA, colB, colC from tableA
union
select colA, null, colC from tableB
```

of course, for example colA type must be the same in all tables... and at the end:

```
order by colC
```

Comment: I have more than 15 tables and they all have same columns. Only the data is different.

Comment: I didn't get your question then completely... If you want just top 100 from from each table then create a subselect...

`select  * from (select top 100 * from tableA)
union
select * from (select top 100 * from table B)`

Comment: Select 100 would mean , getting all the records from each table, Sorting it based on the time and then getting the top 100. (Not selecting 100 from each and then combining.)

Comment: Then my first answer is ok, just embed it in `select top 100 * from ( select... union select ... order by 1)`